# Why is this name bad?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

Earlier I saw someone say that he reported someone for having a character named DrPepper with one of those accents. Is this actually considered bad?

Comment: Is quoting a piece of text that's rather obvious really worth making a question about?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Your account can actually be closed because of this. Here is a section of the [rules of conduct](http://www.swtor.com/legalnotices/rulesofconduct) that clearly says that:

> You may not use names of copyrighted or trademarked characters, materials or products, e.g. Coca-Cola or Dr. Pepper.

Other things that you cannot name characters are names like GeorgeLucas, LukeSkywalker and WinstonChurchill.